# Timestamp as BIGINT(14,0)

Tags: sql, oracle, timestamp

In an oracle table a column SEQNO data type is NUMBER(14,0) looks like it's a timestamp 
of some sort, is there a way to create the SEQNO values ?

Sample data:

```
 SEQNO               Approx Date
34561639054948 = 12-Jul-2007 9:31:45 PM

35052137321439 = 22-Jan-2009 2:28:52 PM

35186025878289 = 22-Jun-2009 1:36:28 PM

35912681320336 = 26-Sep-2011 2:28:51 PM

37471939393482 = 02-Aug-2016 7:12:19 AM

37471943060383 = 02-Aug-2016 7:18:26 AM

37471951296448 = 02-Aug-2016 7:32:09 AM
```

Comment: do you want to convert approx date to seqno?

Comment: i want to add new rows in the database so i need to create the seqno with the current timestamp

Comment: `SEQNO` using timestamp ?

Comment: What is the relation between `SEQNO` and `Approx Date`  ?

Comment: SEQNO seems to be a timestamp of some sort created at "Approx Date", the exact relation between the two is what i'm looking for.